# Run multiple redis server with same data directory

Tags: redis

I have four redis servers running in my env and currently they have separated data directory path with own database, I want to have one common data path for all my redis server, is it possible to do it? any ideas where I should focus if this is possible

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For each server, you should set the same `dir` configuration, while different `dbfilename` and `appendfilename` configurations.

Comment: thanks for the info, I will implement this